# What brand is it?

Tags: identify-this-bike, badge

[image]

I have picked up this old bmx it has a we the people seat, mongoose peddles, kink head, now i just need to know what the frame is please.

Comment: It kinda reminds me of the Sun Microsystems logo, but that's the wrong industry.

Answer (score 6):

The brand is **United**, a BMX company from the United Kingdom.

[image]

It looks like they changed their logo for the following one at some point though:

[image]

**Edit:** Using [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501000000*/http://unitedbikeco.com/) on [http://unitedbikeco.com](http://unitedbikeco.com/), I could see they changed their logo during 2015 as their January 2015 website had the old logo, and the December 2015 version had the new one.