# Need help identifying this logo on 2016 bmx

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx, restoration, badge

I was looking for a bit of help identifying this insignia on this 2016 bmx I'm restoring. Any help would be fantastic[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87867/ which has an answer.   Good luck with your rebuild !